# Integrating this REST GET Request into JQuery or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, rest, linkedin-api

Note: Please be aware that I did not want to disclose my auth key or my company ID and so I have taken precautions to not display them.

I am struggling with Rest calls and reading JSON with a LinkedIn app I am trying to create for my website.

Using this console: https://apigee.com/console/linkedin I am able to request the data I need from a specific LinkedIn company page. However when trying to request the data without using the apigee console, I can't wrap my head around it.

What I need to do is turn the following REST call into a JQuery or JavaScript function on my .html page (on page load).

```
GET /v1/companies/(COMPANY ID)?oauth2_access_token=***************************&format=json 

HTTP/1.1

Host:api.linkedin.com

X-Target-URI: https://api.linkedin.com

Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Could someone please assist me in how to transform this into a proper query that initiates on page load?

Here is an example of something I tried, but did not work:

```
<script>
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/(COMPANY ID)?oauth2_access_token=***************************&format=json ',
        type: 'GET',
        Host: 'api.linkedin.com',
        Connection: 'Keep-Alive',
        success: function () {
            alert('GET completed');
        }
    });
</script>
```

Also I am using the proper GET request correct? The apigee console shows two requests but I am assuming this one:

```
GET https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/(COMPANY ID)?format=json
```

Is the unauthenticated request?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try jQuery's get function:

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

something like this:

```
function success(data){
   ///do stuff if it's ok
}

function error(data){
   ///do stuff if it's not ok
}

/// Define the URL
url = 'https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/(COMPANY ID);

/// Write an object with data to send
sentData = {
   oauth2_access_token : "***************************"
  ,format: "json"
};

/// Finally perform the get request itself
$.get(url, sentData)
   .done(success)
   .fail(error);
```

This is almost what you need. Works well for me.

Comment: Great, thank you! I will give that shot after lunch and credit you if all goes well! :)

Comment: I get this error: XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/(Company ID)?oauth2_access_token=************&format=json. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://(Address).(Domain)' is therefore not allowed access. But if i directly navigate to that URL, I get the JSON info. Whats going on, did I miss a step in authenticating my URL?

Comment: Ah, ok. Are you using that directly from you local filesystem? If you have google chrome you should close all instances (be sure there is no background running, google chrome has this option). Then start it using the command line parameter **--disable-web-security**. This is happening because browsers don't allow cross domain requests from desktop file system (the file:///) protocol.

Comment: But then what will the site visitors need to do in order to view the information? This app is going to be a live feed of the updates my company posts to LinkedIn. The website is being run from a server here at my workplace.

Comment: If is running in a http server there will be no problem, once linkedin api will work fine with cross origin. The problem now is using cross origin from a file:// to http://, this case, browser thinks is insecure and blocks connection (browser, not the server).

Comment: But that's just it, i did the REST call from a web page on the http server and received that error. :/ For example, I load this page http://****.net/****/lin.html and get denied.

Comment: Strange, I can't see your url. Are you sure the company ID (as part of url body) is correct?

Comment: So, disabling web security printed GET successful for me so I am assuming the company ID is correct. However the JSON I am requesting is not being displayed, how would I print out the JSON? preferably without using console log. Thanks for all the help so far Andre.

Comment: I got it to print, now just have to figure out this security issue!